# Checking for letter while input is an int

Tags: python

I have written this code for a user to enter a number, the computer then gives you pi with the amount of numbers after the decimal as selected by the user. I want to check if the user inputs a 'Q' to exit the program. The problem is that when I convert that number into a integer to make sure its not greater than 15, I then can't check to see if that number is q. At the same time if I convert that input to a str, I then won't be able to check if that number is greater than 15, any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
import math
import sys


def piee():
    pie = str(math.pi)
    pi_list = list(pie)

    print(pie)

    try:
        num = int(input("How many numbers after the decimal do I show?, max is 15 - "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a number!")
        sys.exit()

    if num > 15:
        print("That's too large of a number!")
        sys.exit()
    elif num < 1:
        print("That's too small of a number!")
        sys.exit()

    new_num = num + 2
    del pi_list[new_num:]
    final = ''.join(pi_list)
    print(final)
    again = input("Again? [Y/N] ").lower()
    if again == 'y':
        print('+' * 25)
        piee()
    else:
        sys.exit()
piee()
```

Comment: Why don't you do `num = input()` and then `if num == 'q': sys.exit()`?

Comment: Check if it's a "q" before you convert it to an integer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close

```
try:
    inp = input("How many numbers after the decimal do I show?, max is 15 - ")
    num = int(inp)
except ValueError:
    if inp == 'Q':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("That's not a number!")
```

Note you got, `sys.exit()` scattered all over the place. Most of them should just be return.